# Consider a continuous function $f(x)$ with $f(1)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, integral-equations

Given that
$$I_1=\int_0^1x^2f(x)dx=\frac {1}{3}$$ and
$$I_2=\int_0^1(f'(x))^2dx=7$$
Find the value of
$$J=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$
In the first equation using a bit of symmetry I substituted $x=1-t$ and after solving I reached
$$I_1=2\int_0^1xf(x)dx +\int_0^1 x^2f(1-x)dx-J$$

I do not know how to introduce the $I_2$ term in the equation. I tried integration by parts but it just made things messier.